# Is there any way in Sequelize to search on a table with data in another table which is a foreign key to that table?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

My product table

```
const Product = sequelize.define('products', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(12),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    brand: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    instock: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    mrp: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        defaultValue: 0.0,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        defaultValue: 0.0,
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
});

Product.belongsTo(Category, {
    foreignKey: 'category_id',
    as: 'categorys',
});
```

Here the category is a foreign key. I want to search with category name. Do I need to fetch the category first and use the id to search for products?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can search by fields in an associated model, just use `where` option inside `include`:

```js
const products = await Products.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Category,
    as: 'categorys',
    required: true,
    where: {
      name: categoryName
    }
  }]
})
```

If you already have a category id then better search products by it, that way you won't need to use `include` option at all.